# Airflow v2 warning No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql' despite not using this module

Tags: airflow, warnings

We recently upgraded from Airflow v1 to v2 and are currently debugging the new issues that come with such an upgrade. Currently we're getting the following warning message:

```
webserver_1  | [2021-08-21 18:13:45,565] {providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception 
when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLHook' from 
'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'
```

I text-searched our entire project, and there are zero references of `CloudSQLHook`, zero references of `apache-airflow-providers-google`, and zero references of `mysql`... Because of this, we're not sure where to start with eliminating this warning message. How can we resolve this?

Comment: BTW. You can see cross-provider dependencies of Google provider here  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html#cross-provider-package-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google provider has optional dependency on mysql (due to Cloud SQL using mysql as a backend). The easiest way to get rid of the warning is to install `apache-airflow-providers-mysql` package or use [mysql] extra when installing airflow. I also believe newer versions of airflow (quite sure 2.1+) will not log this as a warning.

Comment: good to know. We're having some issues with 2.1+ that should be resolved in 2.1.3 so we're still on 2.0.1, will add [mysql] extra if warnings still appear with 2.1.3

Comment: Yep. It's been fixed in 2.0.2 :) https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14286